# Strange behaviour in JPA2 entities

Tags: jpa-2.0, java-ee-6, ejb-3.1

While observing some log entries, I observed a behaviour, I do not understand.
I have recreated the scenario.

The entity:

```
@Entity
public class SimpleEntity implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 2777681889998131084L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
    @Version
    private Long version;
    @Column(length = 20, nullable = false, unique = true, updatable = false)
    @NotNull
    private String username;
    @Column(length = 60)
    private String email;

    // Constructors

    // getters/setters

    // @Override
    // toString : generated by eclipse, modified to include super.toString
    // hashCode, equals : generated by eclipse, based on 'username'

}
```

The Testcase

```
@Test
public void testUpdate() {
    SimpleEntity simple;
    SimpleEntity simple2;

    try {
        simple = bean.create(new SimpleEntity("user",
                "original@original.com"));  // em.persist
        simple.setEmail("updated@updated.com");
        simple2 = bean.update(simple);          // em.merge
        System.out.println(simple);
        System.out.println(simple2);
    } catch (EJBException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

It prints following lines corresponding to above System.out.println lines

```
...SimpleEntity@36ebea SimpleEntity [id=1, version=1, username=user, email=updated@updated.com]
...SimpleEntity@36ebea SimpleEntity [id=1, version=2, username=user, email=updated@updated.com]
```

What I find strange is the address is same for both entities (**SimpleEntity@36ebea**), but if I look at the data, it is not same. 'version' is different. (**1** & **2**)

How can same instance (as address is same), show different data? Is there some proxy in play? how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`simple` and `simple2` are actually two different instances. You said that "toString : generated by eclipse, modified to include super.toString". The inherited `toString()` from `Object` looks like:

```
public String toString() {
    return getClass().getName() + "@" + Integer.toHexString(hashCode());
}
```

So `@36ebea` is not the object's address, but its hashcode which (being based only on `username`) remains the same for different instances where only the `version` differs.

You might want to use `System.identityHashCode()` to get a hashcode derived from the object's address (it basically returs what you would get from calling `hashCode()` if you didn't override the one inherited from `Object`).